# Проверка водительского удостоверения с помощью ИИ

Tags: машинное-обучение, распознавание-символов

Решил немного понять что такое машинное обучение, модели данных и т.д. имея минимальные знания в этом направлении.

Мне нужно вытащить данные на водительских правах. Я могу сделать распознавание текста на фото с правами, но это будет не совсем то что нужно. Мне нужно понимать какие именно текстовые поля я оттуда достал (что из этого номер, что дата, что имя и тд). Примерно как работает [microBlink](https://demo.microblink.com/in-browser-sdk/blinkid).

Какие модели для этого подойдут, что почитать и что изучить?

Comment: Не надо усложнять. У водительских прав совершенно определенный формат расположения полей, в т.ч. с фиксированным текстом. Если хотя бы в одном из  этих мест изображение не совпадает с ожидаемым, то это не права. Расположение полей с номером, фамилией и т.п. тоже фиксировано

Comment: @avp Определенный только если права постоянно одной и той же страны.

Comment: @Glechik А вы всерьез вознамерились создать систем, которая будет понимать смыл (разбираться где имя, где фамилия, где адрес)? Причем не зависимо - на каком языке (английском, тайском, греческом, иврите), т.к права разных стран? И на этой "простенькой" задаче понять, что такое машинное обучение?

Comment: @passant Что ж вы так яростно возмущаетесь) ОП наверное нужно не промышленного уровня качества достичь, а сделать хотя бы черновой прототип, что в наше время с наличием кучи готовых библиотек и моделей наверное далеко не заоблачно сложная задача. Лично мне кажется, что она просто больше инженерная, чем ML'ная, но если человеку хочется, то можно двух зайцев разом, лишь бы не выгореть на полпути.

Comment: @Glechik, заведите шаблон для каждой из интересующих вас стран и примените простой перебор. KISS принцип

Comment: @passant Хватит только тех стран, где поля дублируюся на английском

Comment: @avp как вариант - не плохо. Но как выразился товарищ AivanF задача не промышленная, а скорее любительская из интереса к данной тематике. Тем более я всего лишь прошу +- неплохую литературу которую можно изучить по данной тематике

Comment: @AivanF Данке) Попросил совет и литературу, получаю вопросы по типу: "ТЫ ШО С УМА СОШЕЛ? ЗАЧЕМ ТЕБЕ?"))

Comment: @Glechik, такое ощущение, что вы хотите литературу на тему -- "как лучше забивать гвозди микроскопом"

Comment: @avp Могу узнать почему у вас такое ощущение?

Comment: Потому что вообще нет смысла использовать нейросети для легко алгоритмизируемых и однозначно решаемых задач.